# What is the difference between the -a and -o options when you use the Pear installer?

Tags: php, pear

When you use the Pear installer, like

```
pear install DB
```

you can use the '`-a`' option or the '`-o`' option.

What is the difference between them?

---

@Ólafur Waage

I want to ask the 
difference between 
all and only.

I cannot understand what they are.

---

What are the 'all' dependencies
and what the 'only' dependencies?

Are there any differences between them?

My brain cannot distinguish them.

---

OK, then, should I use the '`-a`' option?

Comment: Yes, you should use -a, -o is for when you know what you are doing and know what dependencies are installed and are needed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are the short form of `--alldeps` and `--onlyreqdeps`

> The PEAR installer has full support for dependencies; it can automatically install required and/or optional dependencies if you wish so.

Here's the [PEAR Install command manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.installing.php)

EDIT:

What each does is in the manual, but here's the blurb.

> You have several choices:
>
> - Install dependent packages by hand
> - Let PEAR automatically install necessary dependencies only
> - Let PEAR automatically install necessary and optional dependencies
>
> **The first method can be a painful and daunting process, because dependent packages itself can have dependencies.**
>
> Both other methods just require a switch to the install command, either --onlyreqdeps (install required dependencies only) or --alldeps (install all dependencies).